# Автоматическое обновление родительской таблицы, при изменении дочерней

Tags: mysql, sql

На сервере MySQL есть 3 таблицы:

Product:

```
product_id | product_name | date_last_change
    1            name1         2018-10-02
    2            name2         2018-09-25
    3            name3         2018-10-01
```

Component:

```
component_id | component_name
     1             com1
     2             com2
     3             com3
```

Product_components:

```
product_id | component_id
     1            2
     1            3
     2            1
```

В таблице `Product` поле `date_last_change` имеет тип `timestamp`, т.е. при изменении/добавлении любой информации это поле меняется автоматически на текущую дату.

1. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при добавлении/удалении/изменении значений в таблице `Product_components`, соответствующая запись таблицы `Product` обновлялась, т.е. обновлялось бы поле `date_last_change`? Например в таблицу `Product_components` добавили запись (product_id = 2, component_id = 2), в таком случае у 2 продукта в таблице `Product` должно было обновиться поле `date_last_change`?
2. Также нужно обновлять дату последнего изменения в таблице `Product` при изменении его компонента. Например у продукта 1 (из таблицы Product) есть компонент 2 (Из таблицы Product_components), при изменении этого компонента в таблице `Component` должна меняться дата соответствующего продукта в таблице `Product`. Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

P.S. Попытался изложить вопрос понятным языком)

Comment: Задействуйте триггеры. Но не каскадные (вторую задачу надо решать напрямую).

Comment: Добавьте поле `date_last_change` в таблицу `Product_components` и уже при запросах в таблицы `Product`  и `Component `  джойните это значение